# How do I escape characters in a chain of aliases in tcsh?

Tags: shell, tcsh

I want a command `cds` that greps for a string within the output of `dirs -v`, then uses `pd +` to change me to the directory that contains that string without removing it from the ring of directories stored within `dirs`. For instance, if the output of "dirs -v" is

```
0 foo
1 bar
```

then I want the command `cds bar` to execute the equivalent of `pd +1`.

I've defined these:

```
alias dv dirs -v
alias pd pushd
alias pds  "dv | grep \!:1 | awk '{ print "\$1"}'"
```

But getting to the final alias that executes `pd +n`, where n is the current entry in the output from `dirs -v`, is the hard part. Here is one attempt, with output:

```
% alias nds "\\\`pds \\!:1\\\`"
grep: Trailing backslash
```

As you can see, I'm trying to escape the backticks with a backslash, then escape the backslash with another (escaped) backslash. But apparently that doesn't do the job. What do I need to do instead?

Comment: tcsh doesn't seem to let you escape a backtick with a slash like that. Try `echo "foo\`bar"` and see what you get. tcsh is a bit of a mess. Try single quotes during the alias definition since you don't want things being evaluated in there anyway.

Comment: I typically use `alias pds source ~/.tcsh/aliases/pds.tcsh` or some such to avoid the entire problem ...

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is sometimes useful for "flatenning" commands containing backtick-nesting.

In your case, it can be used like:

```
alias nds 'pds \\!:1 | xargs pd'
```

Comment: The problem is that this executes, e.g., "pd 1", while I want it to execute "pd +1". I'm not sure how to squeeze the plus sign and the the number together.

Comment: I just tried this: 

alias nds "pds \\!:1 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/pd +\1/'"

but when I executed "nds foo", I got:

sed: can't read foo: No such file or directory.